# Docker hub images legal background

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is there any legal restriction from docker or software vendors in using standard docker hub images in our production deployments? For example if I use ubuntu:14.04 or mysql docker image from docker hub to start containers in a commercial application, where can I find licensing details for that? Or are they merely free to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a legal than a programming question. Each image will likely have a variety of licenses, often GPL, but could also be BSD, MIT, APL, etc. Most are free to use if you follow their licensing terms. The most common term to consider is whether you will give out the source code of any changes you make upon request from a customer, which they are then completely free to redistribute.

Comment: Thank you. Some of the image descriptionns in docker hub does not have any mentioning about license. Does it mean that those images inherit default license of the original software?

Comment: Almost certainly, very unlikely that anyone is replacing the license on applications they are uploading to docker hub.